# Emacs diagnosis: Org-mode unbearably slow and often stalls

Tags: performance, emacs, org-mode, profiler

My Emacs (GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) under Windows 10 64-bit) has become unusably slow and choppy, especially in Org-mode, e.g. may pause for 2+ seconds to move the cursor and 3+ seconds to refresh to show an expanded tree.

Based on my benchmark-init report, I have done some downsizing by trimming content in my .emacs to reduce require and load statements, changing them into autoload hook or load after eval.

I have also completed a few profiler-report, some of the result looks difficult for me to interpret (e.g. 'line-move-visual' uses lots of memory), and I don't know what packages some of these processes below to and how to tweak and make changes to improve performance. Below is the partially expanded output for profiler-report (mem+cpu), while working on an .org file with around 1500 lines, thanks in advance!

```
(work.org at ~1500 lines)
- command-execute                                         259,247,035  98%
 - call-interactively                                     259,247,035  98%
  - funcall-interactively                                 259,142,758  98%
   - previous-line                                        203,846,889  77%
    - line-move                                           203,846,889  77%
     - line-move-visual                                    92,655,384  35%
      - posn-at-point                                           3,520   0%
         file-remote-p                                          3,520   0%
       window-inside-pixel-edges                               12,844   0%
   - org-cycle                                             46,120,698  17%
    - org-cycle-internal-local                             45,429,666  17%
     - run-hook-with-args                                  45,176,010  17%
      - org-optimize-window-after-visibility-change        41,890,667  15%
       - org-subtree-end-visible-p                         41,862,858  15%
        - pos-visible-in-window-p                           2,111,314   0%
         - jit-lock-function                                  153,338   0%
          - jit-lock-fontify-now                              150,304   0%
           - jit-lock--run-functions                          135,144   0%
            - run-hook-wrapped                                135,144   0%
             + #<compiled 0x2c09399>                          135,144   0%
             #<compiled 0x2cf3709>                             15,160   0%
           file-remote-p                                       18,898   0%
         + eval                                                 1,056   0%
          org-end-of-subtree                                    1,056   0%
       + recenter                                              21,840   0%
      + org-cycle-hide-archived-subtrees                       47,260   0%
        org-cycle-show-empty-lines                              9,232   0%
      + org-cycle-hide-drawers                                  2,936   0%
     + org-show-children                                       12,456   0%
       outline-next-heading                                     5,120   0%
     + org-show-entry                                           1,776   0%
     + outline-flag-region                                      1,520   0%
    + org-hide-block-toggle-maybe                             114,356   0%
    + run-hook-with-args-until-success                         11,744   0%
    + org-cycle-item-indentation                                6,198   0%
    + org-cycle-level                                           5,648   0%
      org-at-table-p                                            5,312   0%
   + execute-extended-command                               8,947,699   3%
   + next-line                                                227,472   0%
  + byte-code                                                 104,277   0%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                           4,519,393   1%
+ elscreen-run-screen-update-hook                              17,698   0%
  internal-timer-start-idle                                     8,137   0%
+ timer-event-handler                                           2,000   0%
+ eldoc-schedule-timer                                          1,056   0%
  ...                                                               0   0%
```

Comment: See this related thread entitled **New (faster) test-build of Emacs 25.1 for Windows**:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5drxs6/new_faster_testbuild_of_emacs_251_for_windows/?st=ivwrzcgk&sh=c742163f

Comment: I should check that out too. I'm currently using the build by zklhp at https://github.com/zklhp/emacs-w64 Thought it wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I used Vincent Goulet's Emacs package bundle in the past, but quite some performance issues appeared after 'upgrading' from Emacs 24 to Emacs 25.1. So I wanted to try out the more as-it-is 64-bit version by zklhp.

Comment: Inasmuch as there are known performance issues with Emacs 25.1 64-bit build (for Windows) that the development team is aware of, it may pay to closely monitor the mailing list and reddit to see how the progress is coming along -- including, but not limited to the latest build described in the thread of the first comment.  A bug fix of the c-source code almost never comes from stackoverflow . . . .  Of course, you will want to try with `emacs -q` -- i.e., no user configuration to see if the problem persists.

Comment: could be related to this question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5760/what-to-do-to-make-orgmode-faster/5780#5780

Comment: Known feature, won't fix!

Answer (score 12):

I found the package that is probably the main reason for the slowdown of Org-mode in my Emacs.

It is the package 'org-bullets' that has not been updated for 2+ years.

By removing its 'require' statement and all the subsequent related settings in my .emacs file, the Org-mode in my Emacs is getting back to state with usable responsiveness.

Comment: Good catch. org-bullets is a big factor in load time for my 8000+ entry org_archive file. The existence of 8000+ properties drawers is the other big factor. Disabling org-bullets and deleting all the PROPERTIES/END pairs (but leaving the actual properties lines) makes the large file load instantly.

Comment: In Windows `(setq inhibit-compacting-font-caches t)` can solve performance issues with many things using "all the icons and fonts." see https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets/issues/11

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is related to your issue, but i also had an extremely slow orgmode on windows, especially when building the agenda.

I found out that the following line solved that for me, when adding it to my big orgmode files:

```
#+STARTUP: showeverything
```

Comment: It doesn't help so much. However, when started with -q org-mode is much faster but the only added actual active minor modes in a normal startup are these two (auto-fill-function tool-bar-mode). It's puzzling how just these two modes decrease the performance so much. Will there be more factors / hidden modes that affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was changing `undo-limit` to 50. The default value is 80000 (on Mac which brew). Unless you really need any huge amount as default you should change that accordingly. For me 50 is good enough.

```
(setq undo-limit 50)
```

**EDIT**
As @Phil pointed out, this variable is related to number of bytes kept in the history buffer. For most of the cases it should be bigger, to not corrupt "undo" feature. If that's an issue, try which value that works best for you.

Comment: That's 50 *bytes* of undo data.  That can't possibly be "good enough" for anyone.

Comment: It would, however, be interesting to use the Emacs CPU profiler to try to find out *why* the default `undo-limit` is causing such issues for you.

Comment: @phils, Yes, after I set this variable I can work which Emacs all day long without slow downs. It could be related to other packages that use undo history as well, like evil, undo-tree or one of many other I use. Either way it works. At first I thought this value is related to number of undo steps rather than bytes od data. Thanks for clarification, I will test it which bigger value and amend my post accordingly.