# Org-mode cursor lagging in 10k file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm experiencing a 2s cursor lagging in a 10K-lines file.
I've looked at other stackoverflow posts
here:

[Slow cursor movement in large Org-mode file and the `org-do-latex-and-related` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990932/slow-cursor-movement-in-large-org-mode-file-and-the-org-do-latex-and-related-f)
and here:

[Emacs diagnosis: Org-mode unbearably slow and often stalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793325/emacs-diagnosis-org-mode-unbearably-slow-and-often-stalls)

and I have tweaked the following variables:

```
auto-save-mode
auto-save-interval
auto-save-timeout
undo-limit
```

and nothing helps.

I have tried disabling the org-bullets package (that wasn't the problem)
and have also checked for snippets that could have been in my init (not the problem).

However, if I disable `org-mode` and go into `fundamental-mode`, than the lagging behavior stops.

I have seen posts complaining of this in other places, and everybody seems to think it's one or another package, but I'm beginning to think this is a more fundamental issue.

Any ideas?

TIA.
Hank

Comment: Have you profiled Org mode to see where it's spending its time? Recent versions of Org mode include a cache for the `org-element` parser that seems to have speeded up many operations. OTOH, there are probably still bugs in that code.

Comment: Hi @NickD - Thanks for the tip. I haven't I, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can read about [profiling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual. What version of Org mode are you using BTW?